# Business Catalyst Creating Multiple Prices For

Tags: adobe, business-catalyst

I have a client that wants to charge different prices for different customers. Some products are discounted 43% and others are at 47% and a promo code only works for a dollar amount discount or a % discount. Is this possible to make customers log in to see special prices based on their log in?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that.  You will need to setup different secure zones subscriptions for each account type. There is a bit of coding involved.

For example, you could setup a 'Retail' and a 'Wholesale' secure zone.  Then, with some javascript/jQuery, you can determine the user's subscription level by sticking the `{module_subscriptions}` tag in a hidden div. When a user is logged in the tag will output the list of secure zones a user is subscribed to and you can then use that to determine which price to display.

HTML:

```html
   <!--stick this before the closing body tag in your template-->
    <div id="userSecureZones" style="display: none;">
        <!--outputs all secure zone subscriptions when logged in -->
        {module_subscriptions}
    </div>

   <!--When the page loads, BC will replace the {module_subscriptions} 
   with something like this-->
    <div id="userSecureZones" style="display: none;">
       <li>
         <ul>
            <!--each one of these represents a zone a user is subscribed to-->
           <li class="zoneName">
             <a href="/Default.aspx?PageID=14345490">Retail Zone</a>
           </li>
           <li class="zoneName">
             <a href="/Default.aspx?PageID=15904302">Wholesale Zone</a>
           </li> 
         </ul>
       </li>
    </div>
```

The code:

```js
function getSecureZone() {
    var loggedIn = !!parseInt('{module_isloggedin}');//true or false
    if (!loggedIn)//user is not logged in
        return false;//

    var subscription = "";
    var zonesList = new Array();

    //grab the zones from our hidden div
    var $zones = $('#userSecureZones .zoneName a');

    //add each zone a user is subscribed to the zonesList array
    $zones.each(function () {
        var zoneName = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
        //add each one to the array
        zonesList.push(zoneName);
    });


    //set the subscription variable to the zone the user is subscribed to
    //if a user can only be subscribed to one zone, then this part is simple
    //if a user is subscribed to multiple zones then list the zone
            //you want to take precedence last.
    if (zonesList.indexOf("RETAIL ZONE")!=-1){
        subscription = "RETAIL";
    }
    if (zonesList.indexOf("WHOLESALE ZONE")!=-1){
        subscription = "WHOLESALE";
    }
    return subscription;//return the zone
}
```

In use:

```js
$(function(){
    var plan = getSecureZone();

    if(plan=="RETAIL"){
      //your code here
    }
    if(plan=="WHOLESALE"){
     //your code here
    }
});
```